# Weak Cryptography (broken algorithm) error

Tags: php, algorithm, cryptography

I have a function that I use for encoding which is like this:

```
$skey = "whateveryoulike"; // you can change it
if(!$value){return false;}
$text = $value;
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

but thing is when I run PHP RIPS scanner for the sake of PCI I get an error on the following line that says: Weak Cryptography (broken algorithm)

```
--> $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

Is there anyone who can point me which Cryptography should I use here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change MCRYPT_MODE_ECB to MCRYPT_MODE_CBC.

Comment: Well tried with CBC but same results...

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Your suggestions makes sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally resolved the issue:

Increasing key length from 15 to 16 because it has to be 16, 24 or 32

```
$skey = "whateveryoulike";
```

to

```
$skey = "whateveryoulikek";
```

and then:

from:

```
$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
```

to:

```
$crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
```

Answer (score 1):

MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is not AES, it is Rijndael with a block size of 256-bits, not a key size of 256-bits. It is best to use AES which has a block size of 128-bits which is RIJNDAEL_128.

Insure th ekey is exactly the correct size, 16, 24 or 32 bytes in length, other wist the function will reject the key or pad it with something, there is no standard for key padding.

Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption.

mcrypt does not support PKCS#7 padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data.

Comment: Well I tried the following but it failed as well: $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

Comment: Perhaps the complaint is also based on mcrypt being used, it is deprecated.